# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' in ipython

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, ipython, psycopg2

This question has been asked before but none of the answers are unsatisfactory condition. I am trying to set up a PostgreSQL database for pandas with jupyter notebook (ipython) always I have following error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'**  the same I have connect with my Django project its working fine.

for this I have Installed following packages even I facing same issue. I am using ubuntu 18.04 bionic verion.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2
pip3 install psycopg2-binary
```

[image]

Comment: is the notebook kernel the same interpreter that you are installing psycopg2 for?

Comment: Yeah looks like different interpreter. Use virtual environments and run projects via venv.

Comment: create a virtual environment using `conda` or `venv` and install everything in it. Launch jupyter from within the environment. It will work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I have a solution for this. I just installed following package and its made my postgres connection.

```
conda install psycopg2
```

Comment: for jupyter notebook !pip install psycopg2 would do

Answer (score 2):

in the notebook cell, execute:

```
!pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Comment: worked for me on Jupyter notebook cell on mac. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed `psycopg2` in ubuntu's default python and you are trying notebook in anaconda's environment. First try installing `jupyter-notebook` in virtualenv where psycopg2 works for `django`. If it works there then its an issue of different environment.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the same venv for jupyter-notebook. Now also facing same issue. But in django works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using a virtual environment. When I try yo execute:

```
!pip install psycopg2-binary
```

It gaves me:

> ```
> bad interpreter: No such file or directory
> ```

When I tried to install the package i need, (in that case psycopg2) like that:

```
!python3 -m pip install psycopg2-binary
```

It worked for me.